# copying an NxN matrix into page of NxNxN matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Ridiculously simple question, but I'd like to get it right: Working in MATLAB, I'm trying to take an NxN matrix and copy it N times to fill an NxNxN matrix. My code executes, but the variable "threeD" is left unchanged after the loop finishes. Also, I'm imagining a loop is not the best way to do this, although I have nothing against it in principle. Thanks in advance!

```
reps = 64;
gradient = (1:reps);
pattern = repmat(gradient,reps,1);

threeD = zeros(reps,reps,reps);

for c = reps
    threeD(:,:,c) = pattern;
end
```

Comment: With broadcasting you can also use `M.*ones(1,1,size(M,1))`, where `M` is your 2D matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1: Using Loops

The for-loop needed to loop from `1` to `reps` which is indicated by `1:reps`.

```
reps = 64;

gradient = (1:reps);
pattern = repmat(gradient,reps,1);

threeD = zeros(reps,reps,reps);

for Layer = 1: reps
    threeD(:,:,Layer) = pattern;
end
```

### Method 2: Using Repmat to Replicate Along the Third Dimension

The second argument in `repmat()`, the array [1 1 reps] indicates how mnay times to replicate the array along the `[row column layer]`/`[x y z]` dimensions.

[image: Replicating Arrays Along Multiple Dimensions]

```
reps = 64;

gradient = (1:reps);
pattern = repmat(gradient,reps,1);

threeD = repmat(pattern,[1 1 reps]);
```

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @nghess No problem, happy to help.